# Access ubuntu machine folder via windows?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-access, shared-folders

I have a ubuntu server that lets me ssh via WSL.

So I have a username and a password and I access it via ssh username@ip

But I want to mount that drive to my windows explorer so that I can access under sublime or any other editor else I have to use vim and sometimes the tabs and spaces in python get messed up.

Any advice?

EDIT:

Updating windows info

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running.  Please provide the exact build number your running.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Windows-style network shares using Samba which is the open source response to Windows smb or cifs.  You can find instructions for installing and configuring Samba for your specific version of Ubuntu but the short version install it and make a folder shared.

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

That should get you started.  You can add shares directly to your smb config file located (usually) here:

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

If you have specific questions, I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: So I can not map it as a network drive and mount it ?

Comment: Of course.  But first you have to tell the server that you want to share it using cifs.  My instructions above are for the Ubu server.

Comment: I don't have sudo access, So can't do that.

Comment: You cannot add software?

Comment: Nope , I am just a standard user

Comment: Might it be possible to get git setup on that server?  That might be a better option anyway.

Comment: I have git installed, So most of the time either I use scp or git.

Comment: I would just use git push and git pull to keep the files up to date.  You can use that over ssh and you get version control as well.  Probably best for you.  No reason to use smb.  Is there something missing for you?

Comment: No, git and ssh to the rescue then.

Comment: Feel free to upvote anything you found helpful here.